# How do I change the entire background color in an RMarkdown HTML Document?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I want to change the background of my RMarkdown document to a very light grey. I discovered how to change themes from this [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html) and I really love the flatly theme. However, I would like to change the entire background to a light grey. See image and output document code below

```
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: monochrome
    theme: flatly
```

[image]

Comment: Don't put "[code and image included]" in your titles. That's never useful information. Code is required (for most questions), and nobody needs to know if an image is included before clicking on the title. Just make sure the title describes your proble, the let the post speak for itself.

Comment: You can add some custom css to your Rmd to do that. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add custom CSS to your document. You can place this line at the top (after the yaml part):

### 1. Inline Style

```
<body style="background-color:grey;">
```

### 2. Embedded Style Sheet

```
<style>
    body { background-color: grey; }
    pre, pre:not([class]) { background-color: red; }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you but could specify where at the top?